# How to get Windows 10 title bar color to preserve when focus is lost?

Tags: windows-10, colors

I changed the accent color in the Windows 10 settings, and set windows to use that accent color for their title bars, but whenever the window loses focus, it reverts back to it's non-colored form. Here's a recording of that happening:

[image: http://imgur.com/w7cEYKp.gif]

Is there some sort of setting I can change in the registry to force the title bars to preserve their color even when they lose focus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is quite easy.

Follow the below steps:-

1. Select a title bar color from the Settings App (Don't select the option to chose color automatically).
2. Go to the following registry key - **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`**
3. Create a new 32bit DWORD named **`AccentColorInactive`**
4. Double click the value named **`AccentColor`** which already exists in the same key as you selected the color in step 1.
5. Copy the value of the **`AccentColor`** to **`AccentColorInactive`**
6. (Optional)Return back to settings app and chose a different color, so that both the color will not be the same.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to get a perfect black color? I tried using the advanced color picker from Win7 (Win+R and then enter "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,Advanced,@Advanced"), but whenever I got close to black, it would change the color to blue. I tried typing in 000000 to the registry key, but same result.

Comment: I was able to set the AccentColor key to 1 (decimal) to get the color to black -- I guess 0 is hardcoded to use blue.

Comment: Note: In the accepted answer above, the color values stored in the AccentColor DWORD are 32-bit values, and are reversed from the RGB hex notation you may be used to. The format is AABBGGRR where AA (alpha) appears to be ignored. This only seems to matter if you want pure black, where you would have to enter `FF000000`.